# #<RedisClient::UnsupportedServer: redis-client requires Redis 6+ when calling perform_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error when using perform_later on my Rails code.

```
#<RedisClient::UnsupportedServer: redis-client requires Redis 6+
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: Try updating the version of redis in gemfile or downgrading the version of active jobs or sidekiq in gemfile. You can also update your redis-client to the latest version to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide more information like which version on ruby,rails and gems like sidekiq, ... This might help you https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/5594#issuecomment-1295838015

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was using old Redis container version. I changed it from 5.0 to the version 6.2.13.
Based on the information of this post bellow:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/5594#issuecomment-1295838015